# Ubuntu 19.10 unable to scan with wifi? no results

Tags: networking, network-manager, 19.10

Just no networks available, while it should be.

tried make interface up/down, restart network manager
No result of any scanning.

no results also here:

```bsh
dkms status
```

here is all info:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 27 Nov 2019 17:25 +05 +0500

Booted last: 27 Nov 2019 00:00 +05 +0500

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.3.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 09:22:33 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8723]
    Subsystem: Realteksaved Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:0726]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723ae

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0f2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp3s0f2' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
4: wlp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
5: enp0s20u3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp0s20u3' [IF3]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.42.131/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s20u3
       valid_lft 2922sec preferred_lft 2922sec
    inet6 fe80::7c90:840f:339e:e83c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp0s20u3  no wireless extensions.

enp3s0f2  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

default via 192.168.42.129 dev enp0s20u3 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s20u3 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.42.0/24 dev enp0s20u3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.131 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

#########
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp0s20u3  no frequency information.

enp3s0f2  no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp4s0    13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp0s20u3  Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp3s0f2  Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp4s0    No scan results

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8723ae]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723ae/rtl8723ae.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723efw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723E 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     A4DD5713D92A721AF200844
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl8723ae
vermagic:       5.3.0-23-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key

parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           aspm:Set to 1 to enable ASPM (default 1)
 (int)
parm:           debug_level:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           debug_mask:Set debug mask (default 0) (ullong)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)
```

PLEASE HELP, have no ideas!

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep -e wlp -e rtl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: The rtl8723ae driver is finding your wireless card. Look in /var/log/syslog* for any messages regarding firmware... I'm looking for something about rtl8723efw.bin firmware not found. In `terminal` do `locate rtl8723efw.bin`. At the GRUB menu, try booting to any other kernel than -23 and see if that works. Lastly, boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if the wireless can scan there. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @chili555 @heynnma Thank you for your replays, i did `upgrade`, after reboot it seems working. I faced that issue many times, re installation of OS was fixing it.
So i think i will face it again in future

Comment: What kernel are you running with now? `uname -r`. Does the `locate` command find the firmware file?

Comment: @heynnema @heynnema in use `5.3.0-23-generic` it was in use before upgrade too.
but i also can see some other karnels:
`find /lib/modules | grep rtl8723ae`
`/lib/modules/5.0.0-31-generic/..`
`/lib/modules/5.3.0-23-generic/..`
`/lib/modules/5.0.0-36-generic/..`

Comment: Reading back... did a reboot fix the problem?

Comment: @heynnema i do no think that reboot fixed it. i did it around 10 times while was playing around trying to fix the issue

Comment: Ok, then you need to provide the information asked for by @chili555 and myself.